# Set Wallpaper fit to screen

Tags: android

I had loaded image using picasa api , But problem is I am not able to set full image as image is scroll able , here is code which i am using so

```
public class Utils {
    private String TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context _context;
    private PrefManager pref;

    // constructor
    public Utils(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = new PrefManager(_context);
    }

    /*
     * getting screen width
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
            // Older device
            point.x = display.getWidth();
            point.y = display.getHeight();
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }

    public void saveImageToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File myDir = new File(
                Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                pref.getGalleryName());

        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Wallpaper-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    _context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#",
                            "\"" + pref.getGalleryName() + "\""),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Wallpaper saved to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(_context,
                    _context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void setAsWallpaper(Bitmap bitmap) {
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(_context); 
    try {

        int widht=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(widht, height);
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }}
}
```

Where I am going wrong........................................................

Answer (score 0):

Is is controlled by any Launcher application. If you want a non-scrolling wallpaper, install a Launcher app that doesn't scroll the wallpaper.
Android OS prior to Jelly Bean does not allow you to programatically set a live wallpaper. For now Jelly Bean supports changing the Live Wallpaper programtically without user interaction